# Is there a way to get torchsummary to deal properly with concatenation?

Tags: pytorch

I have a pytorch U-net model which has tensor concatenation, eg:

```
torch.cat((tensor1, tensor2))
```

When this is included in the `forward()` call of the model, torchsummary ignores it, so I don't see these operations at all.

I made a custom layer to wrap `torch.cat()` and found that it is still ignored unless the model is specified within `__init__`.  That's fine, but now that I have that done, torchsummary complains about trying to find the size of a tuple (the input to the Cat layer).  It seems it assumes that every layer input and output is a single tensor?

Layers with multiple tensors going in and out are not rare.  Is there no workaround?  I'm coming from Tensorflow and simply trying to replicate the `model.summary()` capability.